# What does the -o flag mean in the .NET Core 6 CLI command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

What is the `-o` flag in this .NET CLI command: `dotnet new webapi -o RESTfulAPIName`?

My .Net Core SDK version is 6.0.403.

Comment: Did you try `dotnet new --help` to see the list of options? `couldn't found it anywhere even not on MSDN.` that's not the case. The option is described in all tutorials, in the `dotnet` command itself and in [the dotnet tool's commandline options page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new)

Comment: I did try 'dotnet new webapi -h', but not 'dotnet new -h', very thanx for the help.

Comment: `dotnet new webapi -h` also specifies what the `-o` flag does.

Answer (score 4):

It's the Output flag. It's used to change the location of the scaffolded files to another directory name. By default, the code is placed in `./<ProjectName>/`.

You can see the documentation for this flag by running `dotnet new --help` or [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new), the `-o` flag means:

```
[-o|--output <OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>] [--project <PROJECT_PATH>]
```

Answer (score 1):

It just creates a folder and puts your created .NET project inside it with a specific name.

See this screenshot of my terminal with and without the `-o` option specified below:

[image: Screenshot of a terminal, first with the "-o" flag specified and then without it specified.]

Answer (score 0):

All these answers are very helpful and below is the best answer I found by @gunr2171

It's the Output flag. It's used to change the location of the scaffolded files to another directory name. By default, the code is placed in .//.
You can see the documentation for this flag by running `dotnet new --help` or online.